# Use a Steam Dryer hose for washer fill hose?

Tags: plumbing, washer

I need to install a washer in a tight space that requires a 90 degree angle connection for water hoses. Unfortunately all my local H/W stores don't carry this item, they only have straight connections which kink the hose. I found the following part which is for a steam dryer installation but the fittings are the same (3/4" standard hose fittings). http://www.lowes.com/pd_375855-59288-98538_0__?productId=3573716

Can I use 2 of these hoses for the hot/cold washer fill hoses? My only concern is that the 90 angle piece looks a little small in diameter (smaller than a 3/4" hose) and wasn't sure if that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely **can** use these hoses. In fact, I would recommend them as they appear to be high quality and durable.

The only drawback with any slight restriction would be that it may take slightly longer for your washer to fill, small price to pay versus a burst hose.

PS- you should still turn off the water supply valve(s) whenever you will be gone for more than a few hours.

Comment: I wish the linked website would reveal country of origin, as I prefer to buy domestic products when I can (if they seem "up to snuff"). Product quality is usually higher and it helps our economy.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Country of origin is China. I'm going to try connecting these tonight.